# 'Pixmap' object has no attribute 'getImageData'

Tags: python, pdf-viewer, tkpdfviewer

I am trying to create pdf reader in python and I have used tkPDFViewer library but when i run this according to tkPDFViewer library
and i used tkPDFViewer Library example at first it shows 'Page' object has no attribute 'getPixmap' but when i searched this problem i got an answer in stackoverflow and it said pix = page.get_pixmap() in code font i mean edit tkPDFViewer library by replacing getPixmap to get_pixmap() but when i change that it shows Pixmap' object has no attribute 'getImageData
how do I solve it?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf
import os

root = Tk()
root.geometry('630x700+400+100')
root.title('PDF viewer')
root.configure(bg='white')
def browseFiles():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(),
                                          title='Select a pdf file',
                                          filetypes=(('PDF File','.pdf'),
                                                     ('PDF File','.PDF'),
                                                     ('All File','.txt')))

    v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
    v2 = v1.pdf_view(root,pdf_location=open(filename,'r'),
                     width=77,height=100)
    v2.pack(pady=(0,0))
Button(root,text='Open',width=40,
       command=browseFiles,
       font='arial 20',bd=4).pack()



root.mainloop()
```

#and tkPDFViewer library after editing

```
 try:
    from tkinter import*
    import fitz
    from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
    from threading import Thread
    import math
except Exception as e:
    print(f"This error occured while importing neccesary modules or library {e}")

class ShowPdf():

    img_object_li = []

    def pdf_view(self,master,width=1200,height=600,pdf_location="",bar=True,load="after"):

        self.frame = Frame(master,width= width,height= height,bg="white")

        scroll_y = Scrollbar(self.frame,orient="vertical")
        scroll_x = Scrollbar(self.frame,orient="horizontal")

        scroll_x.pack(fill="x",side="bottom")
        scroll_y.pack(fill="y",side="right")

        percentage_view = 0
        percentage_load = StringVar()

        if bar==True and load=="after":
            self.display_msg = Label(textvariable=percentage_load)
            self.display_msg.pack(pady=10)

            loading = Progressbar(self.frame,orient= HORIZONTAL,length=100,mode='determinate')
            loading.pack(side = TOP,fill=X)

        self.text = Text(self.frame,yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set,xscrollcommand= scroll_x.set,width= width,height= height)
        self.text.pack(side="left")

        scroll_x.config(command=self.text.xview)
        scroll_y.config(command=self.text.yview)


        def add_img():
            precentage_dicide = 0
            open_pdf = fitz.open(pdf_location)

            for page in open_pdf:
                pix = page.get_pixmap()
                pix1 = fitz.Pixmap(pix,0) if pix.alpha else pix
                img = pix1.getImageData("ppm")
                timg = PhotoImage(data = img)
                self.img_object_li.append(timg)
                if bar==True and load=="after":
                    precentage_dicide = precentage_dicide + 1
                    percentage_view = (float(precentage_dicide)/float(len(open_pdf))*float(100))
                    loading['value'] = percentage_view
                    percentage_load.set(f"Please wait!, your pdf is loading {int(math.floor(percentage_view))}%")
            if bar==True and load=="after":
                loading.pack_forget()
                self.display_msg.pack_forget()

            for i in self.img_object_li:
                self.text.image_create(END,image=i)
                self.text.insert(END,"\n\n")
            self.text.configure(state="disabled")

        def start_pack():
            t1 = Thread(target=add_img)
            t1.start()

        if load=="after":
            master.after(250,start_pack)
        else:
            start_pack()

        return self.frame




def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("700x780")
    d = ShowPdf().pdf_view(root,pdf_location=r"D:\DELL\Documents\Encyclopedia GUI.pdf",width=50,height=200)
    d.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: first you have to show code and full error. We can't read in your mind - and at this moment we have no idea what you do and what can make problem. So we can only downvote and/or close your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

current version of Pixmap 1.22.3 has no 'getImageData' method
please use

```
img = pix1.tobytes("ppm")
```

instead of

```
img = pix1.getImageData("ppm")
```

in line no 48 in tkPDFViewer library
after editing the tkPDFViewer library it will be looked like this

```
 try:
    from tkinter import*
    import fitz
    from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
    from threading import Thread
    import math
except Exception as e:
    print(f"This error occured while importing neccesary modules or library {e}")

class ShowPdf():

    img_object_li = []

    def pdf_view(self,master,width=1200,height=600,pdf_location="",bar=True,load="after"):

        self.frame = Frame(master,width= width,height= height,bg="white")

        scroll_y = Scrollbar(self.frame,orient="vertical")
        scroll_x = Scrollbar(self.frame,orient="horizontal")

        scroll_x.pack(fill="x",side="bottom")
        scroll_y.pack(fill="y",side="right")

        percentage_view = 0
        percentage_load = StringVar()

        if bar==True and load=="after":
            self.display_msg = Label(textvariable=percentage_load)
            self.display_msg.pack(pady=10)

            loading = Progressbar(self.frame,orient= HORIZONTAL,length=100,mode='determinate')
            loading.pack(side = TOP,fill=X)

        self.text = Text(self.frame,yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set,xscrollcommand= scroll_x.set,width= width,height= height)
        self.text.pack(side="left")

        scroll_x.config(command=self.text.xview)
        scroll_y.config(command=self.text.yview)


        def add_img():
            precentage_dicide = 0
            open_pdf = fitz.open(pdf_location)

            for page in open_pdf:
                pix = page.get_pixmap()
                pix1 = fitz.Pixmap(pix,0) if pix.alpha else pix
                img = pix1.tobytes("ppm")
                timg = PhotoImage(data = img)
                self.img_object_li.append(timg)
                if bar==True and load=="after":
                    precentage_dicide = precentage_dicide + 1
                    percentage_view = (float(precentage_dicide)/float(len(open_pdf))*float(100))
                    loading['value'] = percentage_view
                    percentage_load.set(f"Please wait!, your pdf is loading {int(math.floor(percentage_view))}%")
            if bar==True and load=="after":
                loading.pack_forget()
                self.display_msg.pack_forget()

            for i in self.img_object_li:
                self.text.image_create(END,image=i)
                self.text.insert(END,"\n\n")
            self.text.configure(state="disabled")

        def start_pack():
            t1 = Thread(target=add_img)
            t1.start()

        if load=="after":
            master.after(250,start_pack)
        else:
            start_pack()

        return self.frame




def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("700x780")
    d = ShowPdf().pdf_view(root,pdf_location=r"D:\DELL\Documents\Encyclopedia GUI.pdf",width=50,height=200)
    d.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).