# Not able to view pdf in tkPDFViewer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

To display pdf in tkinterviewer

[image: 1]

I have tried to display pdf in tkinterViewer but it is throwing below exception

```
Exception in thread Thread-1: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/shana/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "/home/shana/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
   File "/home/shana/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tkPDFViewer/tkPDFViewer.py", line 46, in add_img
     pix = page.getPixmap()
 AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'getPixmap'
```

To display pdf in tkinterViewer

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can offer relevant advice.

Comment: `PyMuPDF` module which `tkPDFViewer` uses has been updated and the function `getPixmap()` is renamed to `get_pixmap()`.  `tkPDFViewer` need to be updated to cater the change.

Comment: @acw1668, After renaming it to get_pixmap(), i got on more error "'Pixmap' object has no attribute 'getImageData'" . This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74235747/pixmap-object-has-no-attribute-getimagedata   helped me finally i displayed pdf. Thanks everyone